# Subset sum problem using key value pairs - python

Tags: python, algorithm, key-value, python-itertools, subset-sum

I have an algorithm that outputs a subset which sums up to a value as close to integer *s* as possible

```
from itertools import combinations

products = {
    "Apple": 5,
    "Pear": 4,
    "Banana": 8,
    "Strawberry": 7,
    "Watermelon": 9,
    "Lemon": 6,
}


def closest_subset(s, nums):
    return min((
        c
        for i in range(1, len(nums) + 1)
        for c in combinations(nums, i)
    ), key=lambda x: abs(s - sum(x)))


print(closest_subset(11, products.values()))

# Output: (5, 6)
```

Instead, I would like to output items from the dictionary, like this:

```
# Desired output
{
    "Apple": 5,
    "Lemon": 6,
}
```

How can I modify my code to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify it, by passing the dictionary items instead of the values to the function. To clarify this, I have replaced `nums` in the code with `items`. The rest of the function works basically the same way, but the combinations give you combinations of tuples containing the key and the value.
Therefore, you have to slightly adjust your `min` function `key`, so that it only takes into account the second value `v2`of each tuple, which is the actual amount. Then, the `min` function returns a tuple pof tuples of key and value pairs, which you can then convert to a dictionary before returning.

```
from itertools import combinations

products = {
    "Apple": 5,
    "Pear": 4,
    "Banana": 8,
    "Strawberry": 7,
    "Watermelon": 9,
    "Lemon": 6,
}


def closest_subset(s, items):
    return dict(min((
        c
        for i in range(1, len(items) + 1)
        for c in combinations(items, i)
    ), key=lambda x: abs(s - sum([v2 for v1, v2 in x]))))


print(closest_subset(11, products.items()))

# Output: {'Apple': 5, 'Lemon': 6}
```